# Como formato um campo DateTime no formato brasileiro dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, formatação

Gostaria de formatar os campos `DataAfr` e `DataTrm` do tipo `DATETIME`, no formato de data brasileiro ***dd/MM/YYYY*** ao invés do formato americano ***yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss***

```
SELECT 
     e.NmrCnt AS [Contrato]
    ,e.NmrSerie AS [Serie]
    ,e.DataAfr AS [Data Aferição]
    ,e.DataTrm AS [Data Término]
FROM
tbl_Eqp e
```

Como devo tratar no `SELECT` ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

User o [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928.aspx), com os parâmetros abaixo.

```
select getdate() as datanormal, Convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103) as dataformatada
```

No seu caso.

```
SELECT 
     e.NmrCnt AS [Contrato]
    ,e.NmrSerie AS [Serie]
    ,Convert(varchar(10), e.DataAfr,103) AS [Data Aferição]
    ,Convert(varchar(10), e.DataTrm,103) AS [Data Término]
FROM
tbl_Eqp e
```

Você ainda tem a opção de usar o [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213505.aspx).

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = getdate();  
SELECT FORMAT (@d, 'd', 'pt-BR' )
```

Answer (score 7):

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DataAfr, 103) AS [Data Aferição]
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15).

Se estiver usando pelo menos o SQL Server 2012 pode usar a função [`FORMAT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) com a opção brasileira.

```
FORMAT(DataAfr, 'dd/MM/yyyy') AS [Data Aferição]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Format.sql).

Answer (score -5):

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())